# Rcpp Class wrapped in S4 object warning

Tags: r, rcpp, roxygen2

I have an R package that utilises an Rcpp Module that contains an Rcpp class that is exposed to the R namespace. The package builds OK and runs fine.

Here is the S4 object definition:

```
#' The main class object
#' @export
setClass("MyObject",
       representation(
            index = "Rcpp_ModuleClass",
            field = "character",
            other_field = "raw"))
```

I keep getting this warning that I found no solution how to get rid of

> Warning: undefined slot classes in definition of "MyObject": index(class "Rcpp_ModuleClass")

Is there a way that I can load an Rcpp module and point the class definition to the definition of the S4 object?

Comment: I need `setClass` to specify an S4 object which can be exported to the package namespace. `devtools::load_all()` is not portable if I want to distribute my package and it still gives me the warning. I have a `R/zzz.R` file and I've not been able to find the correct exported Rcpp class definition for the  module.

Comment: Rcpp Modules expose classes based not on the S4 system, but on the Reference class system (see section 2.2 in the [Rcpp Modules vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf)), which you can read more about [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html). If you want to create an S4 class for use with Rcpp, I'd check out [this reference](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/160_s3_s4.html#s4-class)